# zend framework update from another table

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I got model in Zend Framework what extends `Zend_Db_Table` where `$this->_name = 'tableA'`.

It is very nice how long I doing `insert()`, `update()`, or `delete()`. How I can realize updating main table based on value from another table.. ?

In raw SQL query it could looks like this:

```
UPDATE tableA SET fieldA = tableB.newValue
FROM tableB
WHERE tableA.someValue = tableB.someIndex // it will be complicate manipulation
  AND tableA.index = .....
```

how I can build params for `update()` method:

```
parent::update( $data, $where );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no possible combinations of how to build params for the `parent::update()` method to get that final update query. The reason is because the Db Table `update` method just passes along your `$data` and `$where` variables to the Db Adapter's `update` method. The adapter's `update` method leaves no room for attaching additional information. *You can't hack params at all*

If you can't use table relationships with cascade update. Your best bet will be to extend the Db Adapter and create a new method to handle these types of updates. This should work.

```
/** 
 * Add this method to you custom adapter
 * Direct copy of update method with integration of $from
 * @see Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::update
 **/
public function updateFrom($table, $from, array $bind, $where = '')
{
    /**
     * Build "col = ?" pairs for the statement,
     * except for Zend_Db_Expr which is treated literally.
     */
    $set = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($bind as $col => $val) {
        if ($val instanceof Zend_Db_Expr) {
            $val = $val->__toString();
            unset($bind[$col]);
        } else {
            if ($this->supportsParameters('positional')) {
                $val = '?';
            } else {
                if ($this->supportsParameters('named')) {
                    unset($bind[$col]);
                    $bind[':col'.$i] = $val;
                    $val = ':col'.$i;
                    $i++;
                } else {
                    /** @see Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception */
                    require_once 'Zend/Db/Adapter/Exception.php';
                    throw new Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(get_class($this) ." doesn't support positional or named binding");
                }
            }
        }
        // Reason #1 you can't hack into $data array to pass reference to a table
        $set[] = $this->quoteIdentifier($col, true) . ' = ' . $val;
    }

    $where = $this->_whereExpr($where);

    /**
     * Build the UPDATE statement
     */
    $sql = "UPDATE "
         . $this->quoteIdentifier($table, true)
         . ' SET ' . implode(', ', $set)
         . ' FROM ' . $this->quoteIdentifier($from, true) // My only edit
         . (($where) ? " WHERE $where" : ''); // Reason #2 no room in where clause

    /**
     * Execute the statement and return the number of affected rows
     */
    if ($this->supportsParameters('positional')) {
        $stmt = $this->query($sql, array_values($bind));
    } else {
        $stmt = $this->query($sql, $bind);
    }
    $result = $stmt->rowCount();
    return $result;
}

/** Add this to your extended Zend_Db_Table **/
public function update(array $data, $where)
{
    $tableSpec = ($this->_schema ? $this->_schema . '.' : '') . $this->_name;
    $from      = 'schema.name'; // Get from table name 
    return $this->_db->updateFrom($tableSpec, $from, $data, $where);
}
```

*Note: I didn't test this out, but I am pretty confident it will work as expected. If you have any problems, just let me know. Because I copied the adapter's update method, I went ahead and added notes of the reasons why you can't hack those params.*

**EDIT**
I almost forgot to mention. Every adapter is unique so you will have to check with your adapters update method. I just copied from `Zend_Db_Abstract`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html